# R package revealjs can't change transition

Tags: r, rstudio, r-markdown, reveal.js

I'm trying to create a presentation in RStudio using Rmarkdown and the revealjs package.  I can't seem to change the transition even though I change the yaml to include a different transition as noted in the RStudio [documentation on revealjs](http://rmarkdown.rstudio.com/revealjs_presentation_format.html) and the [github documentation on revealjs](https://github.com/rstudio/revealjs).  I'm running Microsoft R Open 3.3.3, RStudio version 1.0.143, Rmarkdown 1.3, and revealjs 0.9.  Below is some simple code.  I have tried rendering the presentation with both the knit button and in the console.  The transition is stuck on the default box transition.

````
---
title: "Test Presentation"
output: 
  revealjs::revealjs_presentation:
  transition: fade
---

## Slide with Bullets

- Bullet 1
- Bullet 2
- Bullet 3

## Slide with R Code and Output

```{r}
summary(cars)
```

## Slide with Plot

```{r, echo=FALSE}
plot(cars)
```
````

Answer (score 1):

Indenting the 'transition: fade' worked for me.

```
---
title: "Test Presentation"
output: 
  revealjs::revealjs_presentation:
    transition: fade
---
```

Comment: [link]https://github.com/hakimel/reveal.js/#markdown This is the only place I can find mention of indentation being important.  It clearly was in this case.